# JPA Hibernate : Entity marked as dirty when using trim to remove trailing spaces

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entity, flush, spaces

It's been observed that Hibernate marks an entity as dirty when there are trailing spaces in the database value, and trim() is being used in getter/setter.

Our application is using Spring Data JPA (1.6.1.RELEASE) and Hibernate (4.3.0.Final).

```
//getter method -- CUSTOMER_ID column values have trailing spaces in DB
@Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", nullable = false)
public String getCustomerId() {
    return this.customerId == null ? null : this.customerId.trim();
}
 //setter method   
public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
    if(customerId!=null){
        customerId = customerId.trim();
    }
    this.customerId = customerId;
}
```

I did some debuggind and realized that during flush process Hibernate checks if there any changes on entity using `org.hibernate.event.interna.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.dirtyCheck(final FlushEntityEvent event)` method - It has the logic that compares the initial values (loadedState) with the current ones(values).

```
protected void dirtyCheck(final FlushEntityEvent event) throws HibernateException {
final Object[] values = event.getPropertyValues();
..
final Object[] loadedState = entry.getLoadedState();
..
..

if ( !cannotDirtyCheck ) {
                // dirty check against the usual snapshot of the entity
                dirtyProperties = persister.findDirty( values, loadedState, entity, session );
            }
..
..

}
```

So the issue here is that *loadedState* is having the values read from resultSet as is (with trailing spaces, setter method is not used), where as *values* are prepared using getter method - This is causing the entity to be marked as dirty and trigger unwanted UPDATE queries.

Could someone please help me work around this issue OR correct me if I am missing something here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple: The entity has changed (from Hibernate's perspective) and it gets updated in the database.

You can avoid this by either using field access or not having trailing spaces in the database.

Comment: We do not have control on the data already available - Could you please explain what you meant by _field access_ ?

Comment: @aRvi Instead of putting the annotations on the getter/setter put them on the fields itself.

Comment: I changed as below to move access from getter to field - It worked, Great -Thanks to Jimmy T. `@Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID", nullable = false)`
 `@Access(AccessType.FIELD)` 
 `private String customerId;`